# Padding a number with leading 0 in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i have this int (example starts with 10)and i have an incremental function which increments the int so the next number would be 11. I would like to change the int to 010 and 011 etc etc.
I found this code online which helps to pad the number but i am not sure how to display put it to a variable...

```
int intValue = 10;
Console.WriteLine("{0,22} {1,22}", intValue.ToString("D3"), intValue.ToString("X3"));
Console.WriteLine("{0,22:D8} {0,22:X8}", byteValue);
```

i would like to change it so that i can create a new intvalue2(which is not created yet) to be 010.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Numeric values in C# are not zero-padded. You would need to store the padded number in a string variable, or call the number's ToString(), as shown in the MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Comment: Hi Tieson i saw this link during my research but i dont really understand it

Comment: Well, that page is pretty straight-forward, especially the examples toward the end, so you need to spend some time reading it and trying the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.ToString()` method is creating a `string` *not another int*. So the number `010` is not actually a number but a *string*.

`string pInt = intValue.ToString("D3");`

Now `pInt = 010` represented as a string.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer this is what i am looking for but can i ask why i cannot use integer to create the 010?

Comment: As @Tieson T stated C# numeric values are not zero-padded. Therefore you can not make an int be `010` however you can make it `10` and display as `010`.